# How to read from a Firebase Realtime DB with a 'like' query style in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone tell me how I can get the ALL the children `0yV3uJZAoDWCZNHuRgxrUlKYFgz1` from the following firebase node setup:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
self.groupRef
  .child(groupId)
  .queryOrderedByKey()
  .queryStarting(afterValue: userId)
  .queryEnding(beforeValue: userId)
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
               
  })
```

I would like to get the `-1` and `-2` as part of the user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query currently starts and ends at `userId`, which means that you get only one node.

If you want to have all nodes that start **with** the value of `userId`, you'll want to end at the next node. The common trick for this is:

```
self.groupRef
  .child(groupId)
  .queryOrderedByKey()
  .queryStarting(afterValue: userId)
  .queryEnding(beforeValue: userId+"~") // 
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
               
  })
```

The `~` here is not a magic operator, but just one of the last characters in the ASCII table.

Comment: thx for that!!! who would have taught to use that `trick`. Thx again!